# Dedication on Lyx

Tags: lyx

I am using Lyx (template report) and I would like to add a dedication to my family on the 3rd page of my document. Something like this:

[image]

I tried the code `\begin{dedication}` text `\end{dedication}` but got no result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use `\begin{dedication}...\end{dedication}` you would have to define the environment.

Looking at the image you provided, I'm assuming that the header and footer are defined elsewhere. Here is one method to get your `dedication` environment

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for sample text
\newenvironment{dedication}{\phantom{}\vfill\begin{flushright}\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}\raggedleft}{\end{minipage}\end{flushright}\vfill}
\begin{document}

\begin{dedication}
\lipsum[1] 
\end{dedication}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The screenshot isnt mine , i found it on the net while searching , although i want a dedication like the screenshot's .. 
This code you gave me i have to put it on preamble on Lyx ?

Comment: @ALdaperan Just the `\newenvironment...` goes in the preamble. Change the `0.5` to anything you like.

Comment: ook I did it but the dedication appears on the top right side of the page 
Is it possible to put it on the right side but on middle of the page like scrrenshots ?

Comment: @ALdaperan Yes, I've edited it. Note the use of `\phantom{}\vfill`

Comment: With this the dedication went on the bottom right not on middle of the page :(